# Access to fieldLookup results (suitescript 2.0)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm having trouble trying to access to the results of a LookupField search.

```
 var fieldLookUp = search.lookupFields({
                    type: search.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                    id: soid,
                    columns: 'entity'
                });



log.debug('search result', JSON.stringify(fieldLookUp.entity));
```

Here's the log result:

```
[{"value":"1453","text":"101223 Smith Ltd"}]
```

You can see there's a "value" in the object content, so when I try to access to that value, it show me "undefined"

```
 var customer_id = fieldLookUp.entity.value;
```

How can I access to the "value" so I can get the "1453"

I also print the log content of the "fieldLookUp" variable.

```
{"entity":[{"value":"1453","text":"101223 Smith Ltd"}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Rusty Shackles answer guide me to the correct solution.

The correct line of code should be the following:

```
fieldLookUp.entity[0].value
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the object is contained in an array, you do it like this:

```
fieldLookUp[0].entity.value
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did try your suggestion but I still got "undefined"

Comment: I print out the content of the "fieldLookUp" which is look like this:  {"entity":[{"value":"1453","text":"101223 Smith Ltd"}]}

Comment: Here's the complete error I got -  org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "entity" from undefined